# Will grid-lines in textured ceilings show through paint?

Tags: drywall, paint, taping, mudding

We just finished texturing our ceilings with a knock-down texture, however the following day we noticed wide grid-lines in the ceiling everywhere we taped and mudded. We did not prime/seal the sheetrock before texturing (wish we had), but plan to do it now.  Will primer and paint cover these grids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paint will only cover up VERY minor imperfections, like pinholes in a wall (and even then, if it's a big pinhole, it may still show through). If texturing didn't cover it, paint (which is MUCH thinner) definitely won't.